# Properly close Hbase resources in spark streaming job

Tags: hbase, spark-streaming

I am designing a spark streaming job that takes ids from the stream and creates an RDD of ids, RDD operation is to get data for id from hbase tables, process and save to hbase tables. In each spark executor, I create a HbaseConnection using a factory, keep it open for the life of the executor and create new instances of Htable as suggested by Hbase docs at  http://hbase.apache.org/book.html#client.connections. Qn is how to properly close hbase connection in the executors when the streaming job is stopped or killed. I am also thinking of pooling multiple connections within the executor, Looking for suggestions for a good design.